# SequelizeInstance object not rendering in Express Handlebars view (NodeJS,Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js

the error message >>>** Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "first_name" because it is not an "own property" of its parent.
You can add a runtime option to disable the check or this warning:
See https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime-options.html#options-to-control-prototype-access for details
Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "last_name" because it is not an "own property" of its parent.**

**And the data is rendered vert well in my console**

here is the route

```
router.get('/', (req, res)=>
    db.User.findAll()
    .then(allUser => {
        console.log(allUser);
        res.render('home', {
            allUser
        });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err)));


module.exports = router;
```

the home.hbs

```
  {{#each allUser}}
            <tr>
            <td scope="row"></td>
            <td>{{this.first}}</td>
            <td>{{last_name}}</td>
            <td>{{email}}</td>
            <td>{{phone}}</td>
            <td class="text-end">
                <a href="/detail/{{this.id}}" type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-small"><i class="bi bi-eye"></i> View</a>
                <a href="/edituser/{{this.id}}" type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-small"><i class="bi bi-pencil"></i>
                Edit</a>
                <a href="/{{this.id}}" type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-small"><i class="bi bi-person-x"></i> Delete</a>
            </td>
            </tr>
            {{/each}}

        </tbody>
        </table>
```

thanks everyone

Comment: Could help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47329827/sequelizeinstance-object-not-rendering-in-express-handlebars-view-nodejs-expre

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SequelizeInstance object not rendering in Express Handlebars view (NodeJS, Express)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47329827/sequelizeinstance-object-not-rendering-in-express-handlebars-view-nodejs-expre)

Comment: "{{#test_data}}
{{title}}
{{/test_data}}
Where test_data is the name of the variable placeholder and title is name of a field within it. "  this is what i got from there. and in my own case i dont know that variable placeholder means. thanks